# homebrew neo4j not starting

Tags: java, neo4j, installation, homebrew

I installed `neo4j` via homebrew, but when I want to start the server by typing

`$ neo4j start`

I get the following:

```
    Started neo4j (pid 8480). By default, it is available at http://localhost:7474/
    There may be a short delay until the server is ready.
    See /usr/local/Cellar/neo4j/3.0.3/libexec/logs/neo4j.log for current status.
```

The content of the log file is added below (I apologize for the layout).[*1]

I'm using `neo4j` version `3.0.0-M02` and java version `jdk1.8.0_20`(information is included in `.bash_profile`). I'd need to have neo4j running on my Mac (OS X 10.11.5) for a project. I also tried installing it by downloading the `.dmg` file from the [neo4js webiste](https://neo4j.com/download-thanks/?edition=community&flavour=osx&release=3.0.3&_ga=1.197145001.725607697.1466844296), but again no luck (there I get the error

```
    Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@52c870fe' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
```

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

[*1]
**Content of `neo4j.log` file**:

```
2016-06-25 10:27:34.675+0000 INFO  Starting...
2016-06-25 10:27:35.146+0000 INFO  Bolt enabled on localhost:7687.
2016-06-25 10:27:35.449+0000 ERROR Failed to start Neo4j: Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@17013b6f' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception. Starting Neo4j failed: Component         'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@17013b6f' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
org.neo4j.server.ServerStartupException: Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@17013b6f' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
            at         org.neo4j.server.exception.ServerStartupErrors.translateToServerStartupError(ServerStartupErrors.java:68)
    at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:217)
    at org.neo4j.server.ServerBootstrapper.start(ServerBootstrapper.java:87)
    at org.neo4j.server.ServerBootstrapper.start(ServerBootstrapper.java:66)
    at org.neo4j.server.CommunityEntryPoint.main(CommunityEntryPoint.java:28)
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@17013b6f' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:444)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
    at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:189)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.CommunityFacadeFactory, /usr/local/Cellar/neo4j/3.0.3/libexec/data/databases/graph.db
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:144)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.CommunityFacadeFactory.newFacade(CommunityFacadeFactory.java:40)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:108)
    at org.neo4j.server.CommunityNeoServer.lambda$static$31(CommunityNeoServer.java:55)
    at org.neo4j.server.CommunityNeoServer$$Lambda$43/1286783232.newGraphDatabase(Unknown Source)
    at org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase.start(LifecycleManagingDatabase.java:89)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:434)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.Lifecycle$Delegate@4a0448ef' failed to initialize. Please see attached cause exception.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.init(LifeSupport.java:416)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.init(LifeSupport.java:62)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:98)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource.start(NeoStoreDataSource.java:503)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:434)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.state.DataSourceManager.start(DataSourceManager.java:99)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:434)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:140)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.lucene.analysis.core.WhitespaceAnalyzer: method <init>()V not found
    at org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.legacy.LuceneDataSource.<clinit>(LuceneDataSource.java:105)
    at org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.legacy.LuceneIndexImplementation.init(LuceneIndexImplementation.java:76)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.Lifecycles$1.init(Lifecycles.java:37)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.Lifecycle$Delegate.init(Lifecycle.java:63)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.init(LifeSupport.java:406)
    ... 20 more
```

Comment: I believe your server is already started. Just open `http://localhost:7474/` page in your browser .

Comment: Thank you for your response, Vlad. But, unfortunately no, my server is not running. When opening `http://localhost:7474/` in my browser all I see is `Safari can't connect to the server`.

Comment: Ok. The error message is pretty general. I would start by checking the following: does neo4j have write permission where the database folder is set? Is port 7474 free?

Comment: Ok, I checked: port 7474 has nothing running and everyone has write permission to the neo4j database folder.

Comment: You should not use: 3.0.0-M02 it's an outdated milestone. Current is 3.0.3

Comment: Also you're mixing too many things in one question, is the logfile from homebrew or from the DMG?

Comment: I just installed neo4j 3.0.3 via homebrew and it worked seamlessly.

Answer (score 0):

So, the [Neo4j Page](https://neo4j.com/download-thanks/?edition=community&release=3.0.3&flavour=unix) says to run `$NEO4J_HOME/bin/neo4j console`. Additionally I would run it as root (using su or sudo). Please check the write permissions of your neo4j folder also and that port 7474 is free to use.

Neo4j usually provides installation scrips. I believe for your version it is `bin/neo4j-shared.sh`

Comment: Vlad, thank you again for your help, but nothing has worked so far. I ran `$NEO4J_HOME/bin/neo4j console` but again no luck. The error log is still the same.

Comment: Sorry to hear that

Comment: Ah yes, and `neo4j-shared.sh` doesn't do anything on my machine.

Comment: Some more things don't seem to be ok on my machine, tried it on another one and bam: everything works fine. Thank you anyway for your help, Vlad.

Answer (score 0):

The stacktrace is quite clear, there's a classpath clash with a Lucene library. That NoSuchMethodError suggests you have another lucene library installed and visible in the classpath. This causes the classloader to load a different version from the library from the one Neo4J needs.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.lucene.analysis.core.WhitespaceAnalyzer: method <init>()V not found
    at org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.legacy.LuceneDataSource.<clinit>(LuceneDataSource.java:105)
    at org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.legacy.LuceneIndexImplementation.init(LuceneIndexImplementation.java:76)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.Lifecycles$1.init(Lifecycles.java:37)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.Lifecycle$Delegate.init(Lifecycle.java:63)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.init(LifeSupport.java:406)
    ... 20 more
```

A few things to check:

- Do you have lucene installed too?
- Do you have any lucene libraries in the endorsed folder of the jdk?
- Do you have a CLASSPATH variable including a lucene library?
- Did you install more than 1 neo4j version from homebrew? (maybe this left old libraries installed)
- Try to modify the jvm args neo4j receives, and add `-verbose:class` to see from where that class is loaded.

Comment: Some more things don't seem to be ok on my machine, tried it on another one and bam: everything works fine. Thank you anyway for your help, Augusto.

Answer (score -1):

I just tried installing neo4j 3.0.3 on my Mac, worked seamlessly:

```
neo4j-javascript-driver mh$ brew upgrade neo4j

==> Upgrading 1 outdated package, with result:
neo4j 3.0.3
==> Upgrading neo4j
==> Downloading http://dist.neo4j.org/neo4j-community-3.0.3-unix.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100,0%
  /usr/local/Cellar/neo4j/3.0.3: 91 files, 65.1M, built in 38 seconds
Ich:neo4j-javascript-driver mh$ export JAVA_HOME=`java_home -v 1.8`
Ich:neo4j-javascript-driver mh$ killall java
No matching processes belonging to you were found
Ich:neo4j-javascript-driver mh$ neo4j start
Starting Neo4j.
Started neo4j (pid 75890). By default, it is available at http://localhost:7474/
There may be a short delay until the server is ready.
See /usr/local/Cellar/neo4j/3.0.3/libexec/logs/neo4j.log for current status.
Ich:neo4j-javascript-driver mh$ less /usr/local/Cellar/neo4j/3.0.3/libexec/logs/neo4j.log
Ich:neo4j-javascript-driver mh$ less /usr/local/Cellar/neo4j/3.0.3/libexec/logs/debug.log 
Ich:neo4j-javascript-driver mh$ neo4j console
Neo4j is already running (pid 75890).
Ich:neo4j-javascript-driver mh$ neo4j stop
Stopping Neo4j.. stopped
Ich:neo4j-javascript-driver mh$ neo4j console
Starting Neo4j.
2016-06-25 16:25:16.926+0000 INFO  Starting...
2016-06-25 16:25:17.723+0000 INFO  Bolt enabled on localhost:7687.
2016-06-25 16:25:20.667+0000 INFO  Started.
2016-06-25 16:25:22.280+0000 INFO  Remote interface available at http://localhost:7474/
```